# Why is only one result showing from my query?

Tags: mysql

Why am I only getting one result from the query below? The suggested "answer" has the first name "Susan" instead of what I got in my results.

```
SELECT EmpFirstName, EmpLastName, p.ProductName as ProductName, 
YEAR(c.OrderDate) AS Year, 
SUM(o.QuotedPrice + o.QuantityOrdered) AS TotalValue 
FROM Employees 
NATURAL JOIN Products p 
NATURAL JOIN Order_Details o 
NATURAL JOIN Orders c 
ORDER BY Year, TotalValue DESC
```

**Image of results**

[image]

**Image of Table Structure**

[image]

Comment: You are selecting the content of columns that are not part of the group, which is illegal in standard SQL. MySQL allows it, if configured to be “error tolerant” in that regard, but will give you _random_ values from one of the records in the group for those columns.

Comment: Sorry could you rephrase that in a different way? I'm still relatively new to this area of MySQL. The "not part of the group" bit

Comment: Because you are using aggregate(SUM) function in select.

Comment: if you want to sum then use group by clause on order id

Comment: The requirements of my task is to ORDER BY Year, and then the TotalValue in a descending order

Comment: You have only grouped by `Year` and `TotalValue` - which means, those are the only two columns you are _allowed_ to directly select in your column list. You can not select `EmpFirstName`, `EmpLastName`, `p.ProductName` etc., because they are not part of the grouping operation you are performing here. _Because_ grouping combines data from multiple rows, it would simply be ambiguous here - which of the multiple rows should the value be taken from? Not possible to determine, therefor simply not allowed.

Comment: You may also want to reorder your joins (for example Employees and Products don't share any columns - it'll return a Cartesian product of the tables)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. I was able to use my own way to fix it by first grouping by the EmpFirstName and then order by TotalValue in a descending order

Answer (score 1):

Because there are a Sum in your Query

Answer (score 1):

I have here the "same problem" but with count() so I add my problem inside a subquery and works fine. Remember put all condition including where inside the subquery to work properly. Try something like:

```
SELECT M.Id, M.Name,
(SELECT count(L.Id) FROM tblog as L where L.Id = M.Id) as qttlog 
from `tbmember` as M
where M.Id <> 0 and M.Name <> '' 
ORDER BY M.Id asc;
```

change for sum() -

your code:

```
SELECT EmpFirstName, EmpLastName, p.ProductName as ProductName, 
YEAR(c.OrderDate) AS Year, 
(SUM(o.QuotedPrice + o.QuantityOrdered) FROM Order_Details as o WHERE 'condition here') AS TotalValue 
FROM Employees 
NATURAL JOIN Products p 
NATURAL JOIN Orders c 

WHERE 'condition here'

ORDER BY Year;
```

I've made the changes in your code and remove TotalValue DESC because de reference doesn't work (idk why) but the column will have the name.

You forgot the where clause before order by

and you need to inform too the where clause inside the subquery, do not forget that!

I hope it helps you

P.S.:

inside the subquery you can compare with all the atributes selected before de subquery (note the coma only before the subquery - because it's the last element selected) Look first code, I compare with M.Id selected before the subquery)

- remember that: where clause make everything more safe, mainly update and delete

I found something, maybe helps more: after **ORDER BY Year,**

```
 (SUM(o.QuotedPrice + o.QuantityOrdered) FROM Order_Details as o WHERE 'condition here') ASC ;
```

this makes the reference in where clause and works with order by too!

Answer (score 0):

The result returned by the query does not match your expectations because the query is invalid. And your expectations are incorrect.

The presence of an [aggregate (`GROUP BY`) function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) in the expression from the `SELECT` clause requires the presence of a `GROUP BY` clause. When such a clause does not exists, the SQL standard automatically adds a `GROUP BY 1` clause that produces only one group from all the selected rows.

Each expression that appears in the `SELECT` clause of a `GROUP BY` query must follow one of these rules, in order to have a valid SQL query:

1. it also appears in the `GROUP BY` clause;
2. it's a call to an [aggregate (`GROUP BY`) function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html);
3. is functionally dependent of one column that appears in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Because your query does not have a `GROUP BY` clause, the expressions `EmpFirstName`, `EmpLastName`, `p.ProductName` and `YEAR(c.OrderDate)` are not valid in the `SELECT` clause.

Before version 5.7.5, MySQL used to allow such invalid SQL queries but it reserved its privilege to [return indeterminate values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) for the invalid expressions.

Since version 5.7.5, MySQL handles such queries correctly and rejects them. Other RDBMS-es handle them correctly since many years ago.

The explanation for the indeterminate values is simple: the `JOIN` and `WHERE` clauses extract some rows from the table(s). The (missing) `GROUP BY` clause produces only one record from all these rows. A `GROUP BY` query never returns rows from the table, it **generates** the values it puts in the result set. Since there are multiple different values for `EmpFirstName` in the group, the SQL standard says the query is invalid. MySQL used to ignore the standard but it had no valid rule about what value to pick from the `EmpFirstName` expression in the `SELECT` clause. Any value from the rows in the group is equally valid and that's what it returns: one random value from the group.

In order to get the results you expect you have to group the rows by `OrderNumber` and `ProductNumber` (and `EmployeeID` to get a valid SQL query):